# Show that the coefficient of $(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)^m \prod_{1\leq j<i<n}(x_i-x_j)$ is $\frac{m!}{m_1! m_2!\cdots m_n!}\prod_{1\leq j<i\leq n}(m_i-m_j)$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, finite-fields, multinomial-coefficients

> Let $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n\in \mathbb{Z}_0^{+}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^nm_i\geq {n \choose 2}$. Let us write $m=\sum_{i=1}^nm_i-{n \choose 2}$. Prove that the coefficient of  $(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)^m \prod_{1\leq j<i<n}(x_i-x_j)$ in the monomial $x_1^{m_1}x_2^{m_2}\cdots x_n^{m_n}$ is  $$\frac{m!}{m_1! m_2!\cdots m_n!}\prod_{1\leq j<i\leq n}(m_i-m_j).$$

I noticed that the $$f(x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_n)=\prod_{1\leq j<i<n}(x_i-x_j)$$ is the vandermonde polynomial, and I guess  that $\deg(f)={n \choose 2}$ since $f$ is non zero if all the $x_i\neq x_j$.

Now for the other side I have $$g(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)=(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)^m$$ which is pretty simetric and also I guess that a coefficient of $g$ in any monomial is $${m \choose k_1,k_2,\dots, k_n}x_1^{k_1}x_1^{k_2}\cdots x_n^{k_n}.$$

Now I try paste both parts but I can't figure out how I should do it.

I think that I should think how should be the $k_i$ since $\deg (g)=m$ and for get the monomial $x_1^{m_1}x_2^{m_2}\cdots x_n^{m_n}$ I need a monomial of $f$ which degree is ${n \choose 2}$ and complete the sum of $m_i$.

**Edit:**

I try do a particular case when $n=3$ and $m_1=3,m_2=1,m_3=1$ and search the monomial $x_1^3x_2x_3$ and then I expand the polynomial
$$(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)(x_1-x_3)(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2=$$
$$x_2 x_1^4 - x_3 x_1^4 + x_2^2 x_1^3 - x_3^2 x_1^3 - x_2^3 x_1^2 + x_3^3 x_1^2 - x_2^4 x_1 + x_3^4 x_1 - x_2 x_3^4 - x_2^2 x_3^3 + x_2^3 x_3^2 + x_2^4 x_3$$ and first I try watch a regular expression or a pattern, but it seems like there aren't pattern and second I don't get the term and $x_1^3x_2x_3$ in the expression above, now check my calculations and are right, but in these case I don't know where I made the mistake?.

Also I try only expand the vandermonde polynomial for $3$ variables.

$$(x_3-x_1)(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_2)=x_3^2(x_2-x_1)+x_2^2(x_1-x_3)+x_1^2(x_3-x_2)$$

And  I think that for $4$ variables I should obtain $$x_3^3(x_2-x_1)+x_2^3(x_1-x_3)+x_1^3(x_3-x_2)+x^4(x_4-x_1)$$ but it is wrong, and I don't identify a pattern.

Any comment, hint or suggestion is useful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you  tried to explicitly compute the expansion when $n=3$ and $n=4$? What did you get?

Comment: I´m gonna try expand,

Comment: I think that here must be a trick

Comment: is $n=4$ and $m=4$

Comment: in your first case, you chose $m_2 = m_3 = 1$, so the coefficient is zero and that agrees with your claim. Is this a textbook problem?

Comment: It was proposed by a mathematician friend who study polynomial method

Comment: But  I am unable to solve

Comment: if you know the coefficient of the monomial in $(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n)^m$ and in the Vandermonde polynomial, you can sum product of these coefficients over the different ways two monomials multiply to $x^{m_1}x^{m_2}...x^{m_n}$. So if you want the coefficient of $x^3yz^2$ for example, since $x^3yz^2 = xyz * x^2z$, one contribution to the coefficient will be (the coeff of $xyz$ in $(x+y+z)^3$) * (the coeff of $x^3z$ in $(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)$ ).

Comment: I´m new with  Vandermonde polynomial I´m only know that it comes from the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix and about the $(x_1+x_2+\cdots x_n)^m$ I´m only know that a coefficient of the monomial $x_1x_2\cdots x_n$ are given by ${m\choose k_1,k_2,\dots ,k_n}$

Comment: And the problem is that clearly the polynomial $(x_1+x_2\cdots+ x_n)^m$ have degree less than $\sum m_i$ and so I should find in the vandermonde polynomial a term with degree ${n \choose 2}$ for complete the degree $\sum m_i$